# Windows Phone 8 fstream

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, fstream

I'm trying to read from a file and write to a file when developing a Windows Phone 8 application in native C++.

For reading the file I use:

```
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open(fileName);

string text;
while(!inputFile.eof())
{
    string line;
    getline(inputFile, line);
    text += line;
}
```

which works perfeclty fine. But writing to the file does not work no matter what I try.
For example:

```
ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("test.txt", ios::out);
outputFile << "asd" << endl;
outputFile.close();
```

does not even create this file.
If I try to use the same file I used for reading the input it does not work neither. 
I also tried to create a empty file and use that one, with no success.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: firstly you can just do `ofstream outputFile("test.txt", ios::out);` I have no idea why everyone seems to use `.open` first -- there is no need to explicitly close either: look up RAII. Secondly, do you have permission to write to the directory you are in?

Comment: Indeed, when I check the directory properties, "readonly" is checked! But it won't let me uncheck it. How can I give this one file write access?

Comment: I don't have a clue about Windows phone. I guess is that you might not be able to change this for security reasons, find out where user data is supposed to be stored.

Answer (score 3):

You can read any files which are deployed to the phone as part of the app install, but you need to look up the absolute path to these files.

In C++ (actually the C++/CX extension) you can look up the installed location of your app  using:

```
auto appInstallDirectory = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->Path;
```

You can also read/write to your application's local folder in Windows Phone. You can find the location of this using:

```
Platform::String^ localfolder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path;
```

You aren't allowed to read/write files outside of these locations.

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. In this particular case i do not even want to write this file on the phone, but just in my project folder for testing purposes. Does that simplify the situation?

Comment: Ah I see - but the problem is a very similar one. You have to look up the location of the installed files from your project in the phone file system.

Comment: I don't think that the location is the problem, because I can create any file, let's say, in my root directory and read it in with my fstream. But, if I then try to write to this exact same file, it does not work. It really seems to be a problem with my write-access. When I check the Properties of all my folders, it says (readonly), and I am not able to change this.

Comment: What are you calling your root directory? How are you creating the file? How are you checking the properties of the file?

Comment: I am speaking of the root directory of my Project on the Computer. Adding an file to the Visual Studio Project and just reading it in with 
-fstream file("test.txt")-

Comment: That file is on your computer - you can't read it from the phone. The phone has a separate file system which is tightly controlled from the point of view of a 3rd party app such as this.